# Using multi-column SETOF result from a PL/pgSQL function in via jdbc

Tags: sql, postgresql, jdbc, plpgsql

When executing a PL/pgSQL function returning a result of a query, Postgresql jdbc driver seems to return only a single column ResultSet. I cannot figure out how to access the members of the "tuple".

For example, if I have a database

```
CREATE TABLE things (id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, name VARCHAR);
INSERT INTO things (name) VALUES ('pen'), ('eraser');

-- function to return all rows as a SETOF
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION list_things () RETURNS SETOF things AS $$
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY SELECT id, name FROM things;
END
$$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

and I use the PL/pgSQL function *list_things()* from Java like this:

```
static void printThings(Connection c) throws SQLException {
    Statement s = c.createStatement();
    String sql = "SELECT list_things()";
    ResultSet rs = s.getResultSet();
    while (rs.next()) {
        // is String all I can make of it?
        System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
        // how can I access the name member of result row?
    }
}
```

The output looks like

```
(1,pen)
(2,eraser)
```

How can I access the members of tuples other than by parsing the string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
SELECT list_things()
```

to

```
SELECT * from list_things()
```

so it would return rows as they are and not as one tuple with row type